# Compare each value checkbox with each input text id, if checked change value of input text with same id

Tags: jquery, checkbox

How compare the value in jquery multiple checkbox (same name, variable value) to the value of many input text (same name, variable value). And if the checkbox is checked, change the value of the corresponding input text?

```
    var modified = modified; (this is a reference value)        
    if ((checkbox checked value="111" == input text id="111")
    if ((checkbox nochecked value="222" == input text id="222")
    if ((checkbox nochecked value="333" == input text id="333")
    if ((checkbox checked value="444" == input text id="444")

    input text id="111" value="modified"
    input text id="222" value="no changes"
    input text id="333" value="no changes"
    input text id="444" value="modified"
```

I really need it!
thank you very much

Comment: Please edit your question and indent the source code by 4 characters. This will allow to maintain the formatting

Comment: this is some undescriptive pseudo-code ...

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear and difficult to understand, but I'll give my best guess to a response.

When you say "multiple checkbox", I'm curious about what tool you're using. Are you thinking of one of the plugins such as Eric Hynds' multiselect? With that tool, you can fetch an array of all checked values in standard Jquery form:

```
var values = $('#myCheckboxes').filter(':checked').val();
```

Then set up some FOREACH loop and check whether that box's value matches the values of any of the input fields you're interested in. I'd tag all the important input fields with the same class, so you can easily select them.

```
var inputs = $('.allInputs');
for(var i=values.length;i–;){
    $(inputs).each(...); // run a function with each input 
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the question. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Ok let me unwind my brain

Is this what you want to do?

You have a list of checkboxes with different values. If you check one of the checkboxes, a text field with id="value of the checked checkbox" will change its value to "modified". If the checkbox is not checked then the value of the respective text field should be "no changes"?

Try this

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" class="mycheck" value="t111" />
<input type="checkbox" class="mycheck" value="t222" />
<input type="checkbox" class="mycheck" value="t333" />
<input type="checkbox" class="mycheck" value="t444" />

<input type="text" id="t111" />
<input type="text" id="t222" />
<input type="text" id="t333" />
<input type="text" id="t444" />
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mycheck').change(function() {
        if($(this).prop('checked')) {
          $('#' + $(this).val()).val('modified');
        } else {
          $('#' + $(this).val()).val('no changes');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: can you at least confirm that I described your problem?

Comment: sorry for the delay, I'll try to write in dummy code I need: $("input[@type='checkbox'][@name='chave']").each( function() { if(this.checked) { $("#bdcateg").val("categoria")}); Please help me!

Comment: $("input[@type='checkbox'][@name='chave']").each( function() { if(this.checked) { $("#bdcateg")$(this).val().val("modified")});

Answer (score 0):

So simple ... My explanation was confusing. Excuse me!
I wanted only this:

```
    $("input[@type='checkbox'][@name='chave']").each(
    function()
    {
    if(this.checked)
    {                           
    $("#"+this.value).val(categoria);
    }
    });
```

Thanks devnull69 and Topher Hunt for the help!